# Notepad++ TextFX to escape a regular string for regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ TextFX, is there a feature that can escape all reserved characters in a given string? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Like public void Foo() {return this.foo;}. Parenthesis and period should be escaped.

Comment: superuser.com is proably a better place for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not such a tool in the TextFX package that comes with Notepad++.